# Core Data Code for SQL Expression

Tags: sql, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have an entity "booking" with the attributes "name" and "value". Now i would like to have a list of names ordered by the count of entities having this name. In SQL this would look like:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS nameCount 
FROM booking GROUP BY name ORDER BY nameCount
```

I am not able to find any solution to write that with NSSortDescriptor and NSPredicate for Core Data.

Anyone out there able to tranfer this to Core Data?

Comment: EDIT 03.06.2011:

The only way to solve this seems to be to get all names as a distinct union, then request the count for each name from core data and afterwards sort the names based on these counts.

The problem is, that this would mean a request for count for every name in the store. If there are plenty of them this will take a while...

Comment: I have no idea about CoreData or IOS or what database system you use. But can't you define a view (with something like `CREATE VIEW nameCounting AS (SELECT ...)` and then convert the (I guess easier) `SELECT * FROM nameCounting` to CoreData?

Comment: @ypercube Core Data is not an object relational database like sqlite. It only utilizes (for example) sqlite to store object and their relations. As far as I know I can't make use of SQL or other object relational techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a single "booking" entity, your "name" is repeated for multiple records. You could create a separate "name" entity containing just the name along with a to-many relationship to a "booking" entity containing just the "value". You would also want an inverse relationship (not to-many) from the "booking" entity back to the "name" entity. With that in place, you could use @count to get the number of "booking" records for each name.

If the to-many relationship was called "bookings", you could sort or select based on "bookings.@count".

Hope this helps!

Comment: This way I can solve the problem... I never thought about separating the values in different entities. But of course that will work quiet well. Thank you for pushing me in the right direction. ;)